# Implementation of django-directmessages application

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-apps, django-messages

I am trying to use django-directmessages app. It's an application to manage simple direct messages. A part of the [Documentation says](https://github.com/dmonn/django-directmessages):

Import the Message Management API on top of your `views.py`

```
from directmessages.apps import Inbox
```

- Send message: `Inbox.send_message(from_user, to_user, message)`
- List all unread messages: `Inbox.get_unread_messages(user)`
- Read a message (and mark as read): `Inbox.read_message(message)`
- Print a message as : : `Inbox.read_message_formatted(message)`
  Print a list of all conversation partners for a user: `Inbox.get_conversations(users)`
- Get a conversation between two users: `Inbox.get_conversation(user1, user2, _limit_, _reversed_, _mark_read_)`

How can i implement this application in my views.py file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `views.py`, you could implement it like follows:

Have a form, which sends a post request with a message form field to an url like `/chat/<id>/send`, with ID being the user you want to contact.

In your `views.py`, do something like:

```
Inbox.send_message(request.user, User.objects.get(id), request.GET.get('message'))
```